# notification is not getting displayed on the status bar

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I am trying to send a notification on the status bar, this notification should be sent once a button is clicked.
I am using below code and I also referred some examples, but at run time nothing is getting displayed on the status bar on button click event.

please let me know what I am missing

**code-1:send Upstream message**:

```
mBtn_send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_notification);
    mBtn_send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TOAST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            try {
                send();
            } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void send() throws PendingIntent.CanceledException {
    Intent intAct = new Intent(this, ActPending.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intAct, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    //pending.send();

    String title = getString(R.string.app_name);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("BIG TEXT")).setContentText("CONTENTS").setContentTitle(title);
    builder.setContentIntent(pending).setAutoCancel(true);

    ((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)).notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Comment: Do you have any log? If you add a breakpoint in the `send()` method, it's work?

Comment: @Kevinrob i placed a break point at Intent intAct = new Intent(this, ActPending.class); and it is called and nothing was null..should I call `.send`

Comment: And if you go "step by step", is it working? Any logcat?

Comment: Check and see if you have disabled notifications in your device for this app

Comment: @BatCat notifications were disabled on the App. then renabled but nothing changed

Comment: @BatCat I found it..it is because there is not icon set to the notification

Comment: @user2121 Oh lol..ok..Glad that you found it